# How do you get the current directory in a command method?

Tags: 8, console

In a standard Drupal 8 environment, the current working directory is override and becomes the document root of the site. This is a bit troublesome for Drupal Console command implementations that wants to know where the command is running (e.g. import command need that to resolve the given relative path of the target file).

For example:

```php
namespace Drupal\foobar\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Drupal\Console\Core\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

/**
 * Class ImportCommand.
 *
 * Drupal\Console\Annotations\DrupalCommand (
 *     extension="foobar",
 *     extensionType="module"
 * )
 */
class ImportCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function configure() {
    $this
      ->setName('foobar:import')
      ->setDescription($this->trans('Import something'))
      ->addArgument('file', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The file to import');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $this->getIo()->info('execute');

    // **** here ****
    $file = $input->getArgument('file');

    // ...
    // ...
  }

}
```

Now, consider a user running this command:

```
drupal --root=/var/www/html foobar:import ./foobar.json
```

You can virtually run this command anywhere in your system.

The relative path provided to argument `$file` (i.e. `./foobar.json`) is expected to be resolved relative to the runner's current working directory. Normal PHP script can get the information from [getcwd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php). But in a Drupal Console environment, the function `getcwd()` returns the document root of the site.

The normal function `getcwd()` obviously don't work. Is there a way?

Comment: I doubt Drupal would have anything specific, do standard PHP solutions like `__DIR__` not work? If not you'll probably have to trawl through `debug_backtrace` to get that kind of info at runtime

Comment: The constant `__DIR__` specifies where the script is in. Not the working directory of the script caller.

Comment: The Drupal environment overrides the standard working directory variables so `getcwd()` wouldn't work as normal. That's why I need a Drupal-specific way to recover the original `getcwd()` value (if it exists).

Comment: The `$_SERVER` superglobal usually contains env vars when executing PHP from the shell.

Comment: I've checked. The superglobal `$_SERVER` does not provide any variable for a Drupal Console command to retrieve the working directory of the command runner.

Comment: Maybe use [`webflo/drupal-finder`](https://github.com/webflo/drupal-finder).

Comment: `webflo/drupal-finder` solves the opposite of my problem. I do not need to find the Drupal's installation location easily. I need to find the working directory of the original command exection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Drush you use `$this->getConfig()->cwd()`

As I found here https://www.drupal.org/project/drush/issues/297611

They may share enough for this to work.

Edit with a warning:
If you are using Drush directly then this will work. If you are using Drush launcher then it may mess up this context. Generally `/usr/local/drush` or whatever is a launcher. if you call `./vendor/bin/drush` it is not.